# dataset I'm having problems updating row

Tags: dataset

I add the stock with a barcode number.but again, I want to add on the Add button is pressed if the stock.I did, but the bottom line after making adds more to add on.

```
Dim sayac As Integer = 0
    'burdan 
    For i = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1
        If barkodu = GridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "BARKODU") Then
            If GridView2.RowCount > 0 Then

                For s = 0 To stok_ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    If stok_ds.Tables(0).Rows(s).Item("BARKODU") = barkodu Then
                        stok_ds.Tables(0).Rows(s).Item("MIKTARI") += miktari
                        sayac = 1
                        Exit Sub

                    Else
                        stok_ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(stokadi, stokkodu, miktari, barkodu)
                        sayac = 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                stok_ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(stokadi, stokkodu, miktari, barkodu)
                sayac = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If sayac = 0 Then
        MsgBox("sol gridte böyle ürün yok")
    End If
    dgv_siparis_ekle.DataSource = stok_ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohn21.gif

Comment: "but the bottom line after making adds more to add on."
What do you mean? I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I want to get updated line.I do not want to add the line.see picture